# Is there a version of WLLN with weaker conditions than SLLN?

Tags: probability, law-of-large-numbers

Any proof of the weak law of large numbers i know requires conditions under which one can also proofe the strong law of large Numbers. Is there a version of the weak law with conditions so decend, that the strong law does no longer apply?

Answer (score 0):

Sure. Recall that for both WLLN and SLLN you need at least a mean. So try a distribution with no mean, but it's a bit trickier than that. You can find an [example in this link](https://stat.duke.edu/courses/Fall09/sta205/lec/lln.pdf), Example 0.0.1 on the bottom of page 2.

Comment: Thank you a lot, this is very interesting.